# .NET Chart: How to add DataPoint with different member types than double?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, charts, series, datapoint

The namespace I'm looking at is `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting` in .NET Framework 3.5.

I've constructed a `Chart` with name `chart1` and added a `Series` called `mySeries` to that chart.

Within the Data section of that series in the designer, I have:

```
IsXValueIndexed --> False
Name --> mySeries
Points --> (Collection)
XValueType --> DateTime
YValuesPerPoint --> 1
YValueType --> Int32
```

When I try to add `DataPoint`s to the series like this, it seems like I cannot add them with the x and y values of the appropriate type:

```
public void InitializeChart()
{
    Series theSeries = chart1.Series["mySeries"];

    // MyData is of type List<MyDatum> and MyDatum has two members --
    //    one of type DateTime and another of type int

    foreach (MyDatum datum in MyData)
    {
        // I'd like to construct a DataPoint with the appropriate types,
        //    but the compiler wants me to supply doubles to dp

        DataPoint dp = new DataPoint(mySeries);
        dp.XValue = datum.TimeStamp;
        dp.YValue = datum.MyInteger;

        radiosConnectedSeries.Points.Add(dp);         
    }
}
```

What am I missing?  Thanks as always!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DateTime.ToOADate() will return the timestamp as a double that can be used as x value

Answer (score 2):

`DataPoint` doesn't accept other types for x and y. You'll need to use `datum.TimeStamp.Ticks` for ordering/sorting, and then set the `AxisLabel` property (`string`) to display the `DateTime`.

Comment: Thanks (+1).  OK, changing XValueType and YValueType to "Auto" and sending in the x and y as doubles let me plot the graph, but why am I able to specify the types in the designer if I can't actually pass the data in like that?